# Jasmine's toHaveBeenCalled matcher is failing even though I can clearly see my mocked output in the state. The function is def called

Tags: angular, jasmine

so we have a component we are testing which makes a call to the backend which we are mocking:

```
const createComponent = createRoutingFactory({
    component: PvSystemMonitoringOverviewComponent,
    imports: [MonitoringModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [
      mockProvider(PvSystemsApi, {
        loadFiltered: (_x: any) =>
          of([
            {
              id: '5',
              accountId: 'accountid',
              imageUrl: 'imageurl',
              name: 'testone',
              installationDate: 'installationdate',
              standardizedPower: 5,
              address: {
                street: 'mainstreet',
                zipCode: '1100',
                city: 'Wien',
                country: {
                  name: 'Austria',
                  twoLetterIsoCode: 'AT',
                  threeLetterIsoCode: 'AUT',
                },
                state: 'Wien',
                lat: 5,
                lon: 12,
              },
              labels: ['a', 'b'],
              peakPower: 3,
              lastUpdate: '2021-05-25T07:00:00Z',
              energyProductionToday: 6,
              lastErrorMessage: 'disaster',
              healthStatus: HealthStatus.Good,
              connectionStatus: ConnectionStatus.Online,
              openSosCaseCount: 6,
              labelNames: ['a', 'ba'],
            },
          ]),
      }),
    ],
    detectChanges: false,
  });
```

and I set up the spies as follows here:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   spectator = createComponent();
   component = spectator.component;
   pvSystemsApi = spectator.inject(PvSystemsApi);
   spyOn(pvSystemsApi, 'loadFiltered').and.callThrough();
   spectator.detectChanges();
});
```

test is a single line:

```
expect(pvSystemsApi.loadFiltered).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

bearing in mind at this point that I have copied, pasted and edited this from another file testing a component in basically the same way which works.

I know that the output of my loadFiltered is used because I have the following block of code:

```
this.filterQuery.filterCriteria$
  .pipe(
    first(),
    switchMap((criteria) => this.pvSystemsApi.loadFiltered(criteria))
  )
  .subscribe(
    (pvSystems) => {
      console.info('hereisthe pv system' + pvSystems[0].id);
      this.pvSystemsStore.set(pvSystems);
      this.actions.dispatch(PvSystemsActions.pvSystemsLoaded());
      this.pvSystemsStore.setLoading(false);
    },
    (_) => {
      this.pvSystemsStore.setError('Could not load filtered pv systems');
      this.pvSystemsStore.setLoading(false);
    }
  );
```

where I console info pvSystems[0].id, which is my mock return's id value (5), and if I change the number in my mock return, the id changes.  this is the return value of loadFiltered in the pvsystemsapi.

So I know that my mock is being used but the test says

```
Error: Expected spy loadFiltered to have been called.
```